# Is it possible to set method from another class as selector property for NSInvocation object?

Tags: objective-c, selector, nsinvocation

I have a method in ClassA which is called Selector1,

In ClassB I want to create a NSInvocation object and set the Selector1 as the object's selector. Is this possible? I don't know the proper way to set up this.

The code I am trying to use in ClassB is like this:

```
NSMethodSignature *signature = [ClassA methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(Selector1:)];
NSInvocation *invocationToPass = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocationToPass.target = self;
invocationToPass.selector = Selector1; // How can I assign Selector1 from ClassA?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `SEL`, just like the one you passed to `methodSignatureForSelector:`, not just the name of the method.

```
[invocationToPass setSelector:@selector(Selector1:)];
```

You also need to be aware that the colon is significant. If the method takes no arguments, then the name will be `Selector1`; if it takes one, the name is `Selector:`. You need to put the correct name into the `@selector()` operator.